# F# Compare two lists, take different actions

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

How to idiomatically do this: given a list of stuff, find if an item in it meets a criteria in another list, if it does do one action, if it doesn't do another action. I saw code doing this in C# and I wondered how I would do it in F#.

Here is the code as it would be implemented imperatively in F#:

```
let find list1 list2 =
    for i in list1 do
        let mutable found = false
        for k in list2 do
            if i=k then    //if the criteria is equals
                found <- true
                //do task using k & i
        if found =false then   
            //do other task using i
            ()
```

How can this be done more functionally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same idea as yours, only *slightly* clearer. I distilled your "criteria" into an argument function `f : 'a -> 'b -> bool`.

```
let find f xs ys = 
    xs |> List.map (fun x -> (x, List.tryFind (f x) ys))
       |> List.iter (function (x, None) -> printfn "%A" x
                            | (x, Some y) -> printfn "%A,%A" x y)
```

You'd use it like this:

```
find (=) [1;2;3;4] [1;3] (* Prints 1,1 -- 2 -- 3,3 -- 4. *)
```

Comment: Just a quick note. Depending how long those lists are, it might be 'better' from the performance point of view (if we need to improve it) to use [LINQ's `GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, which is kind-of similar to `LEFT JOIN`. Readability may suffer a little bit though :)

Comment: Possibly. I was assuming the function should work for an arbitrary criteria. I wasn't aware that GroupJoin guarantees O(n lg m) running time, though. Does it?

Comment: I don't think it guarantees anything and generally it's hard to tell for sure (since LINQ implementation isn't open), but it *most probably* uses `ILookup/Lookup` and/or `IGrouping` somewhere inside. 'Hash-join'-like implementation shouldn't be too hard in this situation and should be quite fast, so I'd bet my money on that. But that's all speculation.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. On the subject of performance, I should add that my answer is "idiomatic" in the bad sense that we use linear space and not worry about it. If (space) performance were an issue, one should replace `List.Map` with `Seq.Map`.

Comment: Since I'm back home, I can add my 2 cents: for a (left) `outerJoin`, an easy implementation that should be *good enough* [could look like this](http://dotnetfiddle.net/3Pkc6m). No hashing to speak of, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**

```
let crossJoin xs ys =
    xs
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> ys |> Seq.map (fun y -> (x, y)))
    |> Seq.concat
let group f xs ys = ys |> crossJoin xs |> Seq.groupBy f
```

**Longer answer**

In general, when you need to compare every element in one list with every element in another list, you'll need a **Cartesian product**, which you can define like this:

```
let crossJoin xs ys =
    xs
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> ys |> Seq.map (fun y -> (x, y)))
    |> Seq.concat
```

If, for example, you have:

```
let integers = [0 .. 10] |> List.toSeq
let strings = [0 .. 5] |> Seq.map string
```

the Cartesian product would be:

```
> crossJoin integers strings |> Seq.toList;;
val it : (int * string) list =
  [(0, "0"); (0, "1"); (0, "2"); (0, "3"); (0, "4"); (0, "5"); (1, "0");
   (1, "1"); (1, "2"); (1, "3"); (1, "4"); (1, "5"); (2, "0"); (2, "1");
   (2, "2"); (2, "3"); (2, "4"); (2, "5"); (3, "0"); (3, "1"); (3, "2");
   (3, "3"); (3, "4"); (3, "5"); (4, "0"); (4, "1"); (4, "2"); (4, "3");
   (4, "4"); (4, "5"); (5, "0"); (5, "1"); (5, "2"); (5, "3"); (5, "4");
   (5, "5"); (6, "0"); (6, "1"); (6, "2"); (6, "3"); (6, "4"); (6, "5");
   (7, "0"); (7, "1"); (7, "2"); (7, "3"); (7, "4"); (7, "5"); (8, "0");
   (8, "1"); (8, "2"); (8, "3"); (8, "4"); (8, "5"); (9, "0"); (9, "1");
   (9, "2"); (9, "3"); (9, "4"); (9, "5"); (10, "0"); (10, "1"); (10, "2");
   (10, "3"); (10, "4"); (10, "5")]
```

Given the `crossJoin` function, you can easily group these tuples according to a comparison function:

```
let group f xs ys = ys |> crossJoin xs |> Seq.groupBy f
```

Example:

```
> group (fun (x, y) -> x.ToString() = y) integers strings |> Seq.toList;;
val it : (bool * seq<int * string>) list =
  [(true, seq [(0, "0"); (1, "1"); (2, "2"); (3, "3"); ...]);
   (false, seq [(0, "1"); (0, "2"); (0, "3"); (0, "4"); ...])]
```

Now you have a sequence of tuples, where the first value in the tuple is either `true` or `false`.

If, for example, you want to perform a particular action for all matches, you can unpack the groups:

```
> group (fun (x, y) -> x.ToString() = y) integers strings |> Seq.filter fst |> Seq.head |> snd |> Seq.toList;;
val it : (int * string) list =
  [(0, "0"); (1, "1"); (2, "2"); (3, "3"); (4, "4"); (5, "5")]
```

Then you can simply use `Seq.iter` or `Seq.map` to perform the action.

Notice that this uses **lazy evaluation** all the way through.

Unless your actual actions involve manipulating shared state, you have an **embarrassingly parallel** solution at hand, so you could easily spread the work over multiple processors.

Comment: For `crossJoin`, `how about xs |> Seq.collect (fun x-> ys |> Seq.map (fun y-> (x,y)))` ?

Comment: I like how the functions in this answer are broken down into smaller pieces so that they can be reused elsewhere.

Comment: @mydogisbox Yes, your alternative for `crossJoin` works too. It does the same, but is slightly shorter. I think I'll start using that variant instead. Thank you.

Comment: Neat. What does this solution look like if the operator `f` has side-effects and must be applied strictly in the order of the `xs` list?

Comment: @SørenDebois Why would a comparison function have side-effects?

Comment: Sorry, not the comparison operator, but the "do task using" in the original question?

Comment: You could do a `Seq.iter` directly off the result of `crossJoin`, then.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I came up with:

```
let findF list1 list2 =
    list1 
    |> List.iter  (fun i ->  match (List.tryFind (fun k -> i=k) list2)  with
                         | Some(k') -> printfn "i,k=%i,%i" i k'  
                         | None     -> printfn "i=%i" i   )
```

Edit: Updated with correction from comment.

Comment: This doesn't really work since in `match k with`, the `k` is undefined. You probably want to replace `List.tryFind …` and `match k …` with `match List.tryFind ((=) i) with …`.

Comment: @SørenDebois Thank you, I've corrected the mistake now.